# Is it ok to have stubs in the application (not testing) code?

Tags: tdd, bdd, stub

I'm now learning the so called London School of TDD (outside-in approach).

So, I've created an acceptance test for the very first feature and started developing the application and realized that I can use my testing framework's stubs instead of objects that not yet created right in the main, not testing code.

Does this make sence?

Comment: I didn't down vote this myself, but you might want to rephrase the "does this makes sense" part of the question to something leading to less opinionated answers. Try to specify what it exactly is that should make sense or not, and describe that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the London style correctly, you would be focused on testing the interaction flow of your contracts in the code. So unless you didn't use some sort of framework doing that for you (like Moq in .NET), I assume you would (by now) have developed some mocks (stubs) on your own. In that case it sounds very reasonable to promote these into first class objects as part of your production code.

And if your particular language allow it, you can turn it all around. Continue using the former stubs as full class members, and then extend the real implementations to continue using them as mocking objects, testing the interaction with all the collectors and verification code you probably have in them. If you don't have any special test-code in your stubs, then they are basically entities without operations, and then you really don't have a problem using them.

In fact, early on, before all the fancy frameworks existed and we really had to hand-mock everything this was quite common.